# Erro ao tentar calcular o fatorial,por passagem de parãmetro

Tags: c

Estou estudando funções por passagem de parâmetro,o professor pediu para calcular o fatorial de um numero por passagem de parâmetro,o máximo que o consegui foi o código abaixo,ainda sim o código não executa.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void fatorial(int num, long int*fat); 
int main()
{

  int num;
  printf("Digite um numero:\n");
  scanf("%d", &num);
  fatorial(num);
  return 0;
}
void fatorial(int num, long int *fat)
 {
    for(fat = 1; num > 0; num = num - 1)
    {
       fat *= num;
    }
    printf("%ld\n", fat);
 }
```

Comment: O código em compila. Posso ver aqui isso pelo simples bater de olho. "Calcular o fatorial de um número por passagem de parâmetro" é uma frase sem sentido, formule melhor

Comment: O que quer dizer com "calcular ... por passagem de parametro" ? O numero a ser calculado é o único parametro da função ? O resultado do fatorial é suposto ser atribuído num parametro (ponteiro) ?

Answer (score 0):

Refiz seu exemplo tirando o parâmetro `long int *fat` da sua função fatorial e declarei o `fat` como variável local na função.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void fatorial(int num); 
int main()
{

  int num;
  printf("Digite um numero:\n");
  scanf("%d", &num);
  fatorial(num);
  return 0;
}

void fatorial(int num)
 {        
    long fat = 0;    
    for(fat = 1; num > 1; num--)
        fat *= num;             
    printf("%ld\n", fat);
 }
```

Outra alteração seria fazer o fatorial retornar um long, ficando assim

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
long fatorial(int num); 
int main()
{

  int num;
  printf("Digite um numero:\n");
  scanf("%d", &num);
  long fat = fatorial(num);
  printf("%ld\n", fat);
  return 0;
}

long fatorial(int num)
 {
    long fat = 0;
    for(fat = 1; num > 1; num--)
        fat *= num;    
    return fat;
 }
```

Comment: Só um detalhe que o fatorial de 0 é 1.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado valeu, tinha esquecido.